# Global Query Filter only for GET method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table:

```
    [Table("Employee")]  
    public class Employee  
    {  
        [Key]  
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }  
    }
```

And I added soft-delete attribute "IsDeleted". For it I added filter so the soft-deleted data is not showing up when I do GET all employees request. So far it works fine, I get list of all users that are not "IsDeleted" and I can make a request to delete a employee, and then make a get request, and the deleted user is not in the received list. Here is the filter:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{  
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()  
        .HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);  

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);  
}
```

Now the main problem is - how do I make this filter work only with GET request? Because currently, I am only able to set "isDeleted" = true, but I can't restore employee (change "isDeleted" to "false"). Nothing can be done with employees that are soft-deleted.

Comment: Just use `IgnoreQueryFilters()` for "write" scenarios...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with a `DbSet` that has a query filter, but need to access objects that have been filtered, you can use the [`IgnoreQueryFilters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters) method, for example:

```
var deletedUsers = context.Employees
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .Where(e => e.IsDeleted);
```